# Cohen's Kappa in R with no results

Tags: r, correlation

When I use the Cohen's Kappa coefficient to measure the inter-rater agreement between two rates, I cannot get the results. Here I provide a mock example to show the results. Please note that one rater only has a single rating of "A", while the other rater has both "A" and "B" ratings.

```
rater1 = as.factor(rep("A",50))
rater2 = as.factor(c(rep("A", 20), rep("B",5), rep("A", 20), rep("B", 5)))
xy.df = data.frame(rater1, rater2)

library(irr)
kappa2(xy.df, "unweighted")
```

The resultant `z` and p-value are all `NaN` -- is this because one rater has only "A" rating, so there is no variability associated with that rater? **The more important question is, in this situation, how can I proceed to do some other inter-rater analysis?** Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in the intervening years since I answered this question I actually built a statistical package that offers Cohen's kappa. Here's how it works:

```
#Install/load step
require(devtools)
install_github("burrm/lolcat")
require(lolcat)

#Data step
m <- matrix(c(15,3,26,4), nrow=2)
m

cor.cohen.kappa.onesample(m)
```

When run, this particular example gives:

```
> cor.cohen.kappa.onesample(m)

    Cohen's Kappa (Fleiss, et. al 1969 Confidence Intervals)

data:  agreement contingency table
z = -0.10367, null hypothesis kappa = 0, p-value = 0.9174
alternative hypothesis: true kappa is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.5284486  0.4753513
sample estimates:
      kappa    se.kappa   kappa.max         p.o         p.c 
-0.02654867  0.25607611  0.18584071  0.39583333  0.41145833
```

It works for multiple categories too:

```
m <- matrix(c(15,3,5,7,26,4,5,3,27), nrow=3)
m

cor.cohen.kappa.onesample(m)
```

Output:

```
> m <- matrix(c(15,3,5,7,26,4,5,3,27), nrow=3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   15    7    5
[2,]    3   26    3
[3,]    5    4   27
> cor.cohen.kappa.onesample(m)

    Cohen's Kappa (Fleiss, et. al 1969 Confidence Intervals)

data:  agreement contingency table
z = 8.2227, null hypothesis kappa = 0, p-value = 2.22e-16
alternative hypothesis: true kappa is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4338535 0.7054083
sample estimates:
     kappa   se.kappa  kappa.max        p.o        p.c 
0.56963087 0.06927545 0.92030201 0.71578947 0.33961219
```

Hopefully this helps...

Answer (score 1):

I got a code sample to run with the library, but it doesn't appear that the calculation for kappa is correct. One or the other of these should produce a kappa of 1 (based on everything I've worked with, the first example should produce 1, and the second should be -1), but both return -1. I think you might be best off building your own function...

```
require(irr)
x<-matrix( c(20,0,0,20) ,nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(x)<-c("A","B") 
colnames(x)<-c("A","B") 

x
kappa2(x)

#> x
#   A  B
#A 20  0
#B  0 20
#> kappa2(x)
# Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)
#
# Subjects = 2 
#   Raters = 2 
#    Kappa = -1 
#
#        z = -1.41 
#  p-value = 0.157 


x<-matrix( c(0,20,20,0) ,nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(x)<-c("A","B") 
colnames(x)<-c("A","B") 

x
kappa2(x)

#> x
#   A  B
#A  0 20
#B 20  0
#> kappa2(x)
# Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)
#
# Subjects = 2 
#   Raters = 2 
#    Kappa = -1 
#
#        z = -1.41 
#  p-value = 0.157
```